# Swift 4: compiler bugs, is that possible?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am kinda new and tried searching for my answer extensively. Thing is I am getting compile errors which I have no clue why it is.

Example code:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<DeelnemersBestand> = DeelnemersBestand.fetchRequest()
```

`DeelnemersBestand` is a `managedObject` (press option button and hover over `DeelnemersBestand`) and an Entity in my CoreData. I have stated the import CoreData and so on.
Similar code I used in other places in the same code (other classes) as well. Without any errors.

Here comes the strange part. In this class I got a compile error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to specified type 'NSFetchRequest<DeelnemersBestand>
```

So I need to cast it as follows to get rid of the error.

```
 as! NSFetchRequest<DeelnemersBestand>
```

Strange thing is that similar code I use in other classes as well but there I don't get that error.

It puzzles me, anybody any idea what could make it different?

Comment: I can assure you with certainty that this is not a compiler bug.

Comment: Was afraid of that. Sometimes you stare that long to a peace of code that you don't see it anymore .....

Comment: stupid thing is now, I did not change a thing. Only went to another project in Xcode. After getting back this xcode project the errors where gone. :)